# Grid fs returns corrupted file

Tags: node.js, tiff, fs

I am facing the following issue with nodejs and gridfs. I have a bunch of .tif files I store in gridfs with gfs.createWriteStream, all of them are correct (I checked this with gdalinfo).

When I extract the files using `gfs.createReadStream`, some of them are corrupted; several bytes are modified in the tif header.

How can I investigate this problem? Is it also possible to read the chunks to know if they are corrupted?

Here is the code, writing to gfs:

```
const Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
var gfs = new Grid(mongoose.connection.db, mongoose.mongo);

[...]

var readstream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);

var writestream = gfs.createWriteStream({
        filename: filename,
        metadata: metadata,
        mode: 'w',
        content_type: 'image/tiff'
})

[..]

readstream.pipe(writestream);
```

The extraction is similar.

[EDIT]
Actually after further investigations, I realized that the corruption came before GridFs: 
If I create a write stream to disk (using fs) in the mean time I create a write stream to GridFS, I also that same error in the files. So it seems that is is only related to fs TIF read/write ...

```
async.eachLimit(filesToCopy,4, function(file, next) {
    var filePath = path.join(inputFolder, file);
    var readStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
    readStream.on('error') {
        // do something
        next(error);
        return;
    }

    var writestream = fs.createWriteStream(newFilePath);

    writestream.on('close', function(writtenfile) {
        //do something
        next();
    }

    readstream.pipe(writestream);
}, function(error) {
    if (error) {
        callback(error);
    }
    callback(null, ...)
});
```

Comment: Can you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: It is something like this:

Comment: And you can reproduce the issue with that code? It looks okay to me. If bytes get changed, a likely culprit could be that a part of the code is told to interpret the data as UTF-8 instead of binary, but I don't see anything like that happening in the code you posted.

Comment: Yes, it is random but I reproduce it. The corruption of the tif file always occurs the same way, with the same bytes modified.
I was wondering if that would come from the .tif format itself ...

Comment: What values (the actual byte values) are modified, and to what?

Comment: It is always the same ones :
after corruption:

0000000: 4949 2a00 0800 0000 0c00 0001 0300 0100

on the 1st line, I always have the 0800 sequence appearing. Then the .tif can not be used anymore ...

Comment: I would start ruling out encoding issues, it looks like some part of your code is mistakenly converting the binary data to string data (using UTF-8 encoding) before writing it to its destination.

Comment: Thanks for this information.
As I am working with binary files (.tif files actually), how ca I be 100 % sure the files will be managed as binary data ?

Comment: Don't use `setEncoding()` and `toString()`, don't concatenate stream data using string concatenation (`let buffer = ''` and `buffer += data`), things like that. Binary data is typically passed around as `Buffer`, and it should remain that way.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem didn't come from GridFS, nor from the reading.
The problem was that the .tif file was read by node js before it was completely flushed. This explains why it was so random, and why it was always the same byte corrupted.
Setting a timeout before file reading solved the issue.

Thanks robertklep for your posts it helped me finding the solution.